# Changing the style of the toolbar when inflating a searchview like in the GMail app

Tags: android, material-design, searchview

I want to change the style of the toolbar when opening a searchview like in the Gmail app.
It has a toolbar with dark theme, i.e. white icons. When inflating the searchview, the icons change to a light theme, being visible on a white background.
I'm able to achieve this, accessing the single components, for all icons and texts but not the "home as up" indicator, which is controlled by the apps theme / the style setting "colorcontrolnormal".

[image]

[image]

See the picture for the effect I'm trying to describe. There must be a way to change the style of the toolbar from "dark" to "light" programmatically.

I've read the description of the "new" searchview API [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), but there is no option to set the icon of the "home as up" indicator.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is having the same problem :

You can customize the element using

```
  <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```

in your style. Then you can set the color like

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/background_material_light</item>
</style>
```